# How to design full Center Cut FAB in react native navigation

Tags: react-native, material-design, react-native-navigation

I am need to create a custom bottom navigation with floating action button as a full center cut in react native. I will attach the image. I need exactly this and there is not tutorial to follow as at now.I need help. You can drops links I can follow.If you have done something like this,you can share the code   [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did like this in my one project. create "BottomNavigator" component and import it at any class that I wish:

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';
    import { Icon, Button } from 'react-native-elements'
    
    class BottomNavigator extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    flexDirection: 'column',
                    backgroundColor: '#fff'
    
                }}>
                    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', padding: 5, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff', width: 70, height: 70, borderRadius: 35, bottom: 25, zIndex: 5 }}>
                        <Button
                            icon={{
                                name: 'plus',
                                type: 'feather',
                                color: '#fff',
                                style: { marginRight: 0 }
                            }}
                            onPress={() => this.doSomething()}
                            buttonStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#000', width: 60, height: 60, borderRadius: 30 }}
                            containerViewStyle={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: '#3F51B5', bottom: 0, zIndex: 1, width: '100%', height: 60, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingHorizontal: 15, paddingVertical: 10 }}>
                        <Icon
                            name='list'
                            type='feather'
                            color='#fff'
                            onPress={() => this.doSomething()} // Ex : openDrawer() in react-navigation
    
                        />
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <Icon
                                name='heart'
                                type='feather'
                                color='#fff'
                                containerStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }}
                            />
                            <Icon
                                name='search'
                                type='feather'
                                color='#fff'
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    
    
    export default BottomNavigator;
```

And in any class import and use `<BottomNavigator />`.
I am using react-native-elements and vector-icons. It's not necessary just recommended.
Used inline style for your easy edit. I hope this helps you.
[image]

Comment: The material version has a cut in the navigationBar, you just added a white background. 
If the user scrolls an image for example, and it goes behind the button, he will see the white background around the plus FAB